# php types juggling: 'DEP $925'==0.00?

Tags: php, types

Why does php say me `'DEP $925'==0.0` is true?

Can anybody point me to a source for a general rule which covers this case?

--

edit: sorry, initially pasted  wrong expression: `'DEP $925'==''` which, doesn't evaluate to true. Please see now above

Comment: Cannot reproduce: `var_dump('DEP $925'=='');
bool(false)`. Maybe you want to give us some more.

Comment: i don't know if you're trying to use $925 as a variable, but you cannot start a variable name with a number. also: i cannot recreate your problem.

Comment: I don't get the same result. Can you show more code, for context?

Comment: please provide us with more of the surrounding code for reference

Comment: @contagious: It's a single-quoted string, so the $925 is just literal text, not a variable.

Comment: I don't think that is the case but if it was, he'd have to use "" instead of ''.

Comment: It seems, that `$` is used as "dollar" (in the meaning of "currency") here. Thus if I am right, there is no need for `"` (@Zeta) and there is also no problem with the following digits (@contagious)

Comment: What PHP version are you using?  For me, it is evaluated as **false**.

Comment: sorry, initially pasted wrong expression: 'DEP $925'=='' which, doesn't evaluate to true. Please see now above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'DEP $925' == 0.0
string        float
```

Since you're comparing two different data types, PHP will cast one type into the other. In this case, it's casting the string to a float. It won't extract the '925' in there. It'll see the string starts with a `D`, which is not a number, so the string becomes `0`, which is `0.0` float, and compares as equal.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an excellent [comparison operators cheat sheet](http://www.blueshoes.org/en/developer/php_cheat_sheet/) - it shows that a loose comparison between a populated string and an zero integer (be it `0`, `0.00` or `0.000000000`) will return true.

Comment: Cheat sheet probably from [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Comment: @jedwards in fact I've linked to the original (which is easier to use), it's credited at the top of your link: *Inspiration was provided by various user comments and by the work over at » BlueShoes.*

Comment: Wow.  Thats what I get for assuming blogs always copy off official docs.  Thanks for the correction.  Anyway, just meant to add an additional resource, not imply one ref was copying off another.